# What is the chemical composition / empirical formula of Herpes Simplex 1?

Tags: virus

Viruses such as polio are so well documented that a search for "empirical formula polio" gives you something like

```
 C332,652  
 H492,388  
 N98,245  
 O131,196  
 P7,501  
 S2,340
```

We know that the virus consists of 70% protein, 22% phospholipid, 6.5% DNA, 1.5% carbohydrate (from the book *Herpes Simplex and Pseudorabies Viruses* by Kaplan)

Is there any information on the actual chemical composition of HSV1 and varieties?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. What do you mean with atomic arrangement?

Comment: Thanks!  I'm mostly curious about the chemical composition in elements like in the above.

Comment: Thanks! Arrangement sounded like you were interested in the spatial relationships between (all the) atoms

Comment: You should modify your question as people are giving misplaced answers.

Comment: I doubt that such a formula exists for HSV 1, and for good reason: It actually is one of the most massive viruses known

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the atomic composition of viruses has no relevance to contemporary biology.

Answer (score 5):

> The Herpes viruses have a unique four-layered structure: a core containing the large, double-stranded DNA genome is enclosed by an icosapentahedral capsid which is composed of capsomers. The capsid is surrounded by an amorphous protein coat called the tegument. It is encased in a glycoprotein-bearing lipid bilayer envelope [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmllL.png)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK8157/).

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herpes_simplex_virus]

You can watch an animation of infection and steps of replication [here](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/hsvstructure.html), and below the video, they say that

> HSV is a nuclear replicating, icosahedral, enveloped DNA virus. The HSV envelope contains at least 8 glycoproteins. The matrix or tegument which contacts both the envelope and the capsid contains at least 15-20 proteins[[2]](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/hsvstructure.html).

In this definition of the structure, they at least assigned some values to the makeup. Additionally, in wikipedia, the viral genome is listed which I would recommend you take a look at as well. It can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herpes_simplex_virus) but here is the synopsis of the table

```
UL1 through UL56
US1 through US12
RS1, ICP0, LRP1, LRP2
RL1, LAT
```

Additional resources:

1. [HSV Genome 2nd link](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/hsv3f.html)
2. [The use of microarrays to analyze gene expression](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/hsv9fnew.html)
3. [Structural properties of HSV promoters](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/hsv6f.html)
4. [Animation of the Construction of a HSV-1 DNA Microarray for Global Analysis of Transcript Abundance](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/array2.html)
5. [Animation of the Time-dependant Changes in HSV-1 Transcript Abundance During Productive Infection](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/rnatime.html)
6. [Some Genetic Functions Encoded by Herpes Simplex Virus type 1](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/table.html)
7. [Herpes Simplex Virus Oligonucleotide Probes used in the DNA-microarray](http://darwin.bio.uci.edu/~faculty/wagner/probetable.html)